# I'm creating a Navigation Drawer in android studio and I can not set the clicks on the items

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, navigation-drawer

I'm using android studio 3.1.3 I did not find the error, I followed a tutorial but in my case it did not work I searched the source code and found nothing and different follow link:
https://github.com/CursoAndroidMaterialDesign/Navigation-Drawer

Please Help

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.italo.nvigationdrawer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_inbox:{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu Inbox" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_starred:{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu Favoritos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.menu_sent_email:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Enviados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_trash:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Lixeira", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_spam:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Spam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

main activit xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
    />


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Menu class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:title="@string/inbox"
        android:id="@+id/menu_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox"/>

    <item android:title="@string/favoritos"
        android:id="@+id/menu_starred"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_starred"/>

    <item android:title="@string/emails_enviados"
        android:id="@+id/menu_sent_email"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sent_email"/>
</group>

<item android:title="@string/outros"
    android:id="@+id/submenu_outros">
    <menu>
        <item android:title="@string/lixeira"
            android:id="@+id/menu_trash"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_trash"/>

        <item android:title="@string/spam"
            android:id="@+id/menu_spam"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_spam"/>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu >
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhXWR.jpg)

Comment: can you share your activity_main?

Comment: it is already described above, the first code description

Comment: you should post your activity's xml

Comment: activity_main.xml this file

Comment: ok im post now .

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `menu` tag at the root level in `Menu class:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="@string/inbox"
            android:id="@+id/menu_inbox"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox"/>

        <item android:title="@string/favoritos"
            android:id="@+id/menu_starred"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_starred"/>

        <item android:title="@string/emails_enviados"
            android:id="@+id/menu_sent_email"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sent_email"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/outros"
        android:id="@+id/submenu_outros">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="@string/lixeira"
                android:id="@+id/menu_trash"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_trash"/>

            <item android:title="@string/spam"
                android:id="@+id/menu_spam"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_spam"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu >
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onNavigationItemSelected` method try replacing `break;` with `return true;` statement

Comment: @ItaloSilva I always prefer this tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/12648/navigationview-android may be it can help you too

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this code in your drawer project.
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    if (menuItemWaiting != null) {
                        onNavigationItemSelected(menuItemWaiting);
                    }
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    and then add define
  onNavigationItemSelected( final MenuItem item ){

     menuItemWaiting = null;
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                menuItemWaiting = item;
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return false;
            }

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {

                case R.id.nav_home:

                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    break;
    }
}
```